C# - vsto outlook - hide tab
I am creating an add-in using c# vsto .  In the create appointment window, I have added a new tab NewScheduleAssistant using Ribbon(Visual Designer) because the old SheduleAssistant is not suitable for me. And now I need to hide the old SheduleAssistant tab somehow. I tried to use Ribbon XML for this purpose, but it doesn't work with Ribbon(Visual Designer).
Can you tell me any way to hide the SheduleAssistant tab because outlook itself allows me to do it manually?
